# Mysql Date to minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im new using sql, i tried to convert interval to minutes. Is there a developed function that did this.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You put MySQL in the question, but tagged your question with PostgreSQL - which DBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `epoch` and divide by 60.

```
select extract(epoch from <date>) / 60
```

`extract(epoch)` gives the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  So, this gives the number of minutes since 1970-01-01, which seems like a reasonable interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose from tag that you use PostgreSql.

Postgresql has a very good [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). In this link you can find all the date-time functions.

In your case you can use this function to truncate date to minute part:

```
date_trunc(text, timestamp)
date_trunc('minute', date_column)
```

If you need the timestamp, you can cast to timestamp `::timestamp` and then convert to minutes

Comment: Thank you for your response my columb has type interval. Example of data: **01:11:22.534388, 1 day 00:29:50.490655** .

Comment: In your reponse you suggest to use date_trunc but its not really what i need. I want to convert this column to minutes. Example, If column=01:00:01 the value should be 3601. Hope that im clear now